# Not able to set title for command prompt using batch script for the below scenario

Tags: batch-file

I am starting Jboss server 7.01 (windows) container using command prompt. I need to set the command prompt title. So that i can able to kill task using the title. I've tried the below mentioned code, container is started but not able to set the title.

```
START "runas /user:administrator" cmd /K "title=mytitle & cd D:\jboss-7.1.0.Final\bin & d: & standalone_s.bat -<startup script goes here>"
```

I am running this on windows server 2008 r2

Comment: 1. `cd D:\...` --> `cd /D D:\...`, then remove `& d:`. 2. `start "" runas /user:administrator` or `start "mytitle" runas ...`. 3. Why using `start` after all?

Comment: The FIRST set of quotes must be window title if using `Start`. There seems to be no need for `start` in the first place.

Comment: The `TITLE` command does not use an equals symbol.